# List all Enum items (including the one from base class) in python

Tags: python, enums, derived-class

I want to list all enumeration items with a method. The method is defined in the base class as class functions.
The base class has subclasses, and the subclasses have additional subclasses.
I used the python extension extendable-enum.

I updated the example code:

```
from enum import Enum
from extendableenum import inheritable_enum
import inspect


@inheritable_enum
class baseClass(Enum):
    BASEELEMENT= 'Baseelement'

    @classmethod
    def list(cls):
        classHierachy = inspect.getmro(cls)
        for singleClass in classHierachy[0:-2]:
            print(singleClass.__name__)  # debug output
            print(list(map(lambda singleClass: singleClass.name, eval(singleClass.__name__))))

    def get_list_with_bases(class1, output=None):
        if output is None:
            output = []
        try:
            names = list(class1)
        except TypeError:
            return output
        for class2 in class1.__bases__:
            get_list_with_bases(class2, output)
        output.extend(names)
        return output


@inheritable_enum
class middleClass(baseClass):
    MIDDLECLASSELEMENT = 'middleClassElement'

class endClass(middleClass, baseClass):
    ENDCLASSELEMENT = 'endClassElement'


print(endClass.BASEELEMENT)
print(endClass.MIDDLECLASSELEMENT)
print(endClass.ENDCLASSELEMENT)
endClass.list()
# endClass.get_list_with_bases(endClass)
```

Expected output:

```
baseClass.BASEELEMENT
middleClass.MIDDLECLASSELEMENT
endClass.ENDCLASSELEMENT
endClass
['ENDCLASSELEMENT']
middleClass
MIDDLECLASSELEMENT
baseClass
BASEELEMENT
```

But I get:

```
baseClass.BASEELEMENT
middleClass.MIDDLECLASSELEMENT
endClass.ENDCLASSELEMENT
endClass
['ENDCLASSELEMENT']
middleClass
[]
baseClass
[]
```

Comment: There's no need to use `eval(cls.__name__)`. That's the same as just `cls`.

Comment: Do you want this to work to understand it? Because to do what you're trying to do, a `dict` is all you need and using `extendable-enum` seems terribly convoluted. Also, there's a typo in your example (but apparently not in the code you ran - which suggests you're not sharing the actual code you're running) - "TEWNTYTWO".

Answer (score 2):

According to the example available in the project repo it looks like it can't be accessed that way

https://github.com/gweesip/extendable-enum/blob/main/docs/examples/example_inheritable_enum.py

```
# And create a subclass with new members
class MoreFruit(Fruit):
    MANGO = 4
    DRAGONFRUIT = 5

# Only the non-inherited members will be in _member_names_
print(MoreFruit._member_names_)

# Inherited members are not included in dir, len, reversed or iteration
print(dir(MoreFruit))
print(len(MoreFruit))
print([member for member in reversed(MoreFruit)])
print([member for member in MoreFruit])

# Inherited members can not be accessed by name
try:
    MoreFruit['APPLE']
except KeyError:
    print('Access to super members by name not supported')

# or by value
try:
    MoreFruit(1)
except ValueError:
    print('Access by value not allowed')

# but can still be accessed as attributes.
print(MoreFruit.APPLE)
# The returned members are the superclass members.
print(MoreFruit.APPLE is Fruit.APPLE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer by @Dakolas, there is not direct way to list all enum names.

Use `.__bases__` as a workaround:

```
# And create a subclass with new members
class MoreFruit(Fruit):
    MANGO = 4
    DRAGONFRUIT = 5

print(list(MoreFruit) + list(MoreFruit.__bases__[0]))
```

As a more general solution, write a recursive function to visit all base classes on all levels:

```
def get_list_with_bases(class1, output=None):
  if output is None:
    output = []
  try:
    names = list(class1)
  except TypeError:
    return output
  for class2 in class1.__bases__:
    get_list_with_bases(class2, output)
  output.extend(names)
  return output

# And create a subclass with new members
class MoreFruit(Fruit):
    MANGO = 4
    DRAGONFRUIT = 5

print(get_list_with_bases(MoreFruit))
```

Comment: Hi pts,

the recursive function does not work on my side. I get the error: NameError: name 'get_list_with_bases' is not defined.

Comment: It works for me, maybe you copy-pasted it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

It generally helps to make code simpler if you're trying to understand a problem with it.

This does something very similar to your code, but greatly simplified:

```
from enum import Enum
from extendableenum import inheritable_enum


@inheritable_enum
class ExampleA(Enum):
    A = 1


class ExampleAB(ExampleA):
    B = 2


print(ExampleAB.A, ExampleAB.A.value)
print(ExampleAB.B, ExampleAB.B.value)

for x in ExampleAB:
    print('x:', x)
```

Instead of multiple classes adding things, there's a simple base class `ExampleA` that only has `A` in it, with value `1`. And the derived class `ExampleAB` that also has `B` in it, with value `2`.

Instead of the method you had, that could have been written like this as user @Barmar pointed out in the comments:

```
    @classmethod
    def list(cls):
        return list(map(lambda c: c.name, cls))
```

I've just added a simple `for` loop at the end that also iterates over everything in the enum and shows what is inside.

The output:

```
ExampleA.A 1
ExampleAB.B 2
x: ExampleAB.B
```

This clearly shows that:

- `ExampleAB` does indeed make the values from both classes available.
- The actual value of `ExampleAB.A` is still `ExampleA.A` from the superclass.
- If you loop over ExampleAB, it only really contains `ExampleAB.B`, it won't include values from the base class.

However, if you just want this functionality, a `dict` would be a simpler and better choice of course:

```
exampleA = {
    'A': 1
}

exampleAB = exampleA | {
    'B': 2
}

print(exampleAB['A'])
print(exampleAB['B'])

for x in exampleAB:
    print('x:', x, 'value:', exampleAB[x])
```

Output:

```
1
2
x: A value: 1
x: B value: 2
```

Comment: Hi Grismar

I want to get the enum of all class-hierachies.
I tried it with this function but the result is the same. even if I address each class individually:
I will post it as reply